# How long an investment will take to compund to a target amount

Tags: calculus, finance

> A man with $\$20,000$ to invest decides to diversify his investments by placing $\$10,000$ in an account that earns $7.2\%$ compounded continuously and $\$10,000$ in an account that earns $8.4\%$ compounded annually. Use graphical approximation methods to determine how long it will take for his total investment in the two accounts to grow to $\$35,000$.

Teacher said the answer is: $7.3$ years

But i don't know how to solve it.

Please help me.

**FORMULAS:**

Compounded Continuously: $A=Pe^{rt}$

Compounded Annually: $A=P(1+r)^t$

$A$ - Money after t years 
$P$ - Principal amount invested
$r$ - rate of investment 
$t$ - time in years 
$e$ - the value $e$ used in $\ln$

Comment: If it's graphical approximation methods, shouldn't your goal be to just graph it and estimate the numbers based off of that? It doesn't sound like your teacher is actually asking for a precision answer.

Comment: You're looking for a value of $t$ that satisfies $$10000e^{0.072t}+10000(1.084)^t = 35000$$.

Comment: Oh that's true @mardat but I don't know how to graph it to get the answer.

Comment: @MPW Can you factor out 10,000? When I did, I got the answer of 14.639, I think. How does one  get 7.3?

Comment: @Audrey: Yes, then the equation becomes $$e^{0.072t} + 1.084^t =3.5$$ and it should have the same solution set. These equations can't be solved exactly, only by some approximation method.

Comment: Is this right @MPW? t(0.072+ ln(1.084)) = ln3.5

Comment: +1 for making compound interest interesting! (with the !)

Comment: @Audrey: No, that's not valid. It would be correct if the terms were multiplied instead of added. Unfortunately, the logarithm of a sum can't be simplified, usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \$10,000 account at 7.2% interest gets you $10000e^{0.072t}$ dollars in $t$ years. The other \$10,000 investment gets you $10000(1+0.084)^t$ dollars in $t$ years.

So in $t$ years, you have $10000e^{0.072t}+10000(1+0.084)^t$ total dollars. We can make this a bit easier by factoring out the $10000$, so the amount of money in $t$ years, $M(t)$, we have is $M(t)=10000(e^{0.072t}+1.084^t)$.

We want to know in how many years will this be \$35,000. That is, we want $M(t)=35,000$. So
$$
10000(e^{0.072t}+1.084^t)=35,000
$$
Divide by the 10,000 to get
$$
e^{0.072t}+1.084^t=3.5
$$
Since your teacher wants this graphically, go into the calculator (I'll assume you have a TI-83 or TI-84) and graph the function $e^{0.072t}+1.084^t$ as Y1. Then for Y2 3.5. Then when you graph them, look where they intersect. That $x$ value where the lines touch will be the amount of years you want. Be careful about choosing an appropriate window! (But since we divided by the 10,000, this shouldn't be a problem - the only reason I did that). You can do this without having to 'guess' by using the 2nd - CALCULATE - then INTERSECT to find the intersection of the curves and make the calculator do all the work.

To get an idea of what you should see, trying looking at [this plot here.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph%20y%3De%5E%7B0.072t%7D%2B1.084%5Et%20and%20y%3D3.5)

Comment: Oh I see, this was really helpful. We don't use calculators in our classes though :(

Comment: If you aren't allowed calculators of *some* sort, you cannot solve this. Doing this graphically typically means using a graphing calculator. But if you only have a basic calculator, just graph this the way you would back when you first learned how to graph - plus in a value for $t$, get the value for $y$, plot the point, and repeat. Then connect the points, draw a horizontal line at $y=3.5$, then estimate your answer as best you can. If your calculator does not have $e$ on it, remember $e\approx 2.718281828$.

Comment: @Audrey It is important that you can only solve this numerically, meaning you eventually have to use a calculator or computer of some sort. There is no exact numerical answer (or at least at the level of your class).

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much. I will try to get a hold of a calculator for this class.

Answer (score 3):

Everything you need is in the graphic per the instructions.

As mentioned in the comments and shown in the graphic, you could also solve for $t$ using numerical methods like Newton's Method.

The equation becomes:

$$10000e^{.072 t}+10000(1+0.084)^t = 35000 \implies e^{.072 t}+(1.084)^t = 3.5$$

The result is $t = 7.32505 ~~\mbox{years}$ (see update below for more details).

Here is the graphical representation (look at the point for the vertical line):

[image]

**Update**

We can solve this numerically (Fixed Point Iteration, Secant Method, Newton's Method ... Others). Using Newton's Method, we have the iteration formula:

$$t_{n+1} = t_n- \dfrac{f(t)}{f'(t)} = t_n - \dfrac{e^{0.072 t_n} + 1.084^{t_n} -3.5}{0.0806579 \times 1.084^{t_n} + 0.072e^{0.072 t_n}}, ~ t_0 = -22$$

This converges in $13$ steps to $t = 7.325046477477088$.

Comment: Alright, so how do you solve it numerically? We don't have the graphing calculators.

Comment: We weren't introduced to Newton's method.

Comment: Check with your teacher, but just judging by the nature of the question, and the fact that you don't know Newton's Method, I would assume it's something you don't need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Using pencil, paper, eraser and a hand calculator that has exponential functions calculate and plot the graph, taking $1,000 as convenient unit :

$$ A(n) = 10 ( 1 + .072)^n + 10 ( 1 + .084)^n $$

EDIT1:

corrected (oversight error) to include continuous compounding:

$$ A(n) = 10\  e^{0.072 \, t} + 10\ ( 1 + .084)^n $$

for n upto 8 years. It takes ~7.32505 years to reach 35.